# iOS Database I/O disk error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm still learning iOS development and I was trying to use a database to save my records. When I try to insert the first time it does successfully. But when I do another insert operation the "Disk I/O error" comes up even though select statements work just fine.

Here's some code snippets. I'm testing on a simulator.

```
- (IBAction)addToFavBtnPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    sqlite3_stmt *favStmt;

    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString* insertsql = @"";
        if(_appDelegate.detailsDescription == nil)
            {insertsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO favs (ID, TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, FULL_DESCRIPTION, SMALL_IMG, LARGE_IMG) VALUES (\"%d\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", _event._id.integerValue, _event.title, _event.startDate, _event.endDate, _event.briefDescription, _event.fullDescription, _event.smallImage, _event.largeImage];
            }else {
            insertsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO favs (ID, TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, BRIEF_DESCRIPTION, SMALL_IMG, LARGE_IMG) VALUES (\"%d\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", _appDelegate.eventId, _appDelegate.detailsTitle, _appDelegate.detailsStartDate, _appDelegate.detailsEndDate, _appDelegate.detailsDescription, @"", @""];
            }
        const char *insert_statment = [insertsql UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_statment, -1, &favStmt, NULL);

        if(sqlite3_step(favStmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Celebrating already %@", _event.title);
            UIImage *activatedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"likeactivated.png"];
            [_addToFavBtn setBackgroundImage:activatedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error %s while preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"booo hooo");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(favStmt);
    sqlite3_close(_db);
}

-(void)openOrCreateDb {
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favs.db"]];

    const char *dbpath =[_databasePath UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_statement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favs (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, TITLE TEXT, AR_TITLE TEXT, START_DATE TEXT, END_DATE TEXT, BRIEF_DESCRIPTION TEXT, FULL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, AR_BREIF_DESCRIPTION TEXT, AR_FULL_DESCRIPTION TEXT, SMALL_IMG TEXT, LARGE_IMG TEXT, AR_SMALL_IMG TEXT, AR_LARGE_IMG TEXT)";

        if(sqlite3_exec(_db, sql_statement, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You forgot to close the database in the `openOrCreateDb` method. 2) You don't log any error if the `sqlite3_exec` method fails. 3) In `addToFavBtnPressed` you close the db even if it doesn't open. You finalize the statement even if you don't prepare the statement. 4) You are building queries with `stringWithFormat` instead of properly binding values into the prepared statement. 5) You don't check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.

Comment: Yes I know all of that lol, I'm just testing and am very new to iOS, anyways what you mentioned doesn't fix my issue right?

Comment: Fix all of the issues. Then see if you still have the problem. Those issues need to be fixed regardless.

Comment: Will do. I will post back results ASAP.

Comment: I don't know how to fix points 4 and 5.

Comment: #5 is done like all of the other checks - look at the return value. #4 is unrelated to your issue but should be fixed. There are plenty of examples. Search on using `sqlite3_bind_text`.